# Places Library returns Unable to authenticate the supplied URL. Please check your client and signature parameters

Tags: google-places-api

I have a simple google places library implementation.

```
var place_service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
place_service.search(request, place_callback);
```

It stops working if the browser (Chrome) is left open for several days, untouched. Upon trying the next search, I get 403 error from the library search call.

> Unable to authenticate the supplied URL. Please check your client and signature parameters.

Here is the captured request [URL](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/PlaceService.FindPlaces?1m6&1m2&1d39.3949084235794&2d-87.69731253091982&2m2&1d39.4038915764206&2d-87.68568746908022&2sen-US&6sbicycle_store&6sbook_store&6sclothing_store&6sconvenience_store&6sfurniture_store&6shardware_store&6sjewelry_store&6sliquor_store&6spet_store&6sshoe_store&6sshopping_mall&6sstore&6sdepartment_store&6shome_goods_store&6selectronics_store&callback=_xdc_._1ij4pa&token=17871):

Closing browser and restarting fixes.

Also have a mobile HTML mobile app (iOS, Android) with same implementation. The apps places functionality also stops working after several days. App must be killed and restarted to fix.

Something seems to be expiring?

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behaviour, the `token` parameter in the request can expire after as little as a few hours. I would recommend issuing a page refresh when the user returns if the page or app has been dormant for more than a few hours.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is this documented in the Places API ? And would the direct places HTTP calls avoid this problem ?

Comment: This is not documented however put in place to minimise service abuse and yes a HTTP requests would avoid this.